# What is the best way to render navigation with the Phoenix Framework?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'd like to include a navigation bar in the app.html.ex template. Something like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My app</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="help">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to render the `ul` so it can attach `class="active"` according to the current controller?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen a method to render an navigation yet.
Alternatively you can write some helper methods.

To set `class="active"` I add some methods to the `layout_view.ex`.

```
def is_example_path(conn) do 
  controller_module(conn) == MyApp.ExampleController
end
```

So you can Add something like this to your template.

```
<ul>
  <li class="something <%= if is_example_path(@conn), do: " active" %>">Example</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. As a temporary solution, this works but we need something more generic... maybe a macro would work!

Comment: For those experiencing a problem following this example, you may need to fully qualify the `controller_module/1` function name, as in: `Phoenix.Controller.controller_module(conn)`.